# mapping actions from a nemespaced vuex modules into components methods works only with one of the 2 avialable syntaxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This works just fine:

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('event', ['fetchEvents'])
  }
```

But if I change it to this:

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['event/fetchEvents'])
  }
```

then this errors apear in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.fetchEvents is not a function"

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>                                                                   vue.runtime.esm.js:587


TypeError: "this.fetchEvents is not a function"
        created EventList.vue:29
        VueJS 17                                                                 vue.runtime.esm.js:1737
```

​
What am I doing wrong here? both of these syntaxes are legit based on vuex documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't indicate an alias for the action it must be called like this:

```
this['event/fetchEvents']
```

If you wish to call the action like `this.fetchEvents` you should call `mapActions` like this:

```
...mapActions({
  fetchEvents: 'event/fetchEvents'
})
```